# Minecraft Registration

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I purchased the Minecraft game for computers at Gamestop this weekend.  I have been trying to register a new account for 4 days and it just says they we are currently updating our system and it won't be long.  Does anyone know how long this will be since it has been 4 days already and I have a very eager kid wanting to play this...thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: To start off, have you been able to create a Mojang Account / get past the Mojang Account Registration screen?

Comment: No, that's whee it says updating our system.  I was wondering if anyone had a tip on how to bypass this or if they knew how long it would be, it has been since Saturday.

Comment: Where are you trying to register? I can access their registration page just fine.

Comment: You might want to try one more time now - I was able to register an account with no issues. Be sure you're registering at the correct page. (https://minecraft.net/store/minecraft)

Comment: This is the error I just got using that link.

Comment: Sorry, we can’t set up your account at the moment. We are currently updating our system - but it shouldn’t be long

Comment: When do you get the error? I just tried that and got up to being told to validate my email. I didn't try going any further than that because it'd involve actually accessing the email I used.

Comment: As soon as I hit create account it gives me that error, I never get an email to validate?

Comment: I know its not working for everyone, but does anyone know for how much longer.  I have been trying for 4 days to register this account.  I have a very persistent kid driving me nuts...lol

Comment: Thank you all for your help, oddly enough I was able to register it using internet on my phone.....strange but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you visit https://help.mojang.com/ you will see that minecraft.net is not working for everyone at the moment. This is the website where you register new accounts.

[image: minecraft.net is down]

Keep checking back at https://help.mojang.com for updates.

If the service goes back to green and you still can't register the account, contact Mojang Support at: https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/emails/new?ref=footer

Comment: Over the past several days sometimes the minecraft.net will show green, but I have still been unable to register.  I have emailed their customer service but have gotten no response.

Comment: They are likely not responding due to issues with the server going up and down. You could always return your purchase at GameStop and buy the account directly from Mojang instead since it sounds like that worked for crayzeedude. Either way, this is not a known issue with known workarounds, so you're going to have to keep trying with Mojang. We can't really help you here with this issue.